# batch script - was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch, script

when attempting to run my batch script then I got the following the error message.

Message:

```
C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\NIC_fix>nic.bat
\Windows\Setup\Scripts\NIC_Fix\devcon.exe was unexpected at this time.

C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\NIC_fix>for /f "delims=:" \Windows\Setup\Scripts\NIC_Fix\devcon.exe findall *dev_07B0*') do C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\NIC_Fix\devcon.exe remove "@x"

C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\NIC_fix>
```

Here is my batch script:

```
for /f "delims=:" %x in ('C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\NIC_Fix\devcon.exe findall *dev_07B0*') do C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\NIC_Fix\devcon.exe remove "@%x"

C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\NIC_Fix\devcon.exe rescan
```

thanks,

EDIT1:

Script:

```
for /f "delims=:" %xx in ('%SystemRoot%\Setup\Scripts\NIC_Fix\devcon.exe findall *dev_07B0*') do %SystemRoot%\Setup\Scripts\NIC_Fix\devcon.exe remove "@%xx"
%SystemRoot%\Setup\Scripts\NIC_Fix\devcon.exe rescan
```

output:

```
C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\NIC_fix>nic.bat
SystemRootSystemRootxx" was unexpected at this time.

C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts\NIC_fix>for /f "delims=:" SystemRootSystemRootxx"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### batch script - was unexpected at this time

In a batch file you need to use `%%a` **not** `%a`.

> FOR command variables <del>which</del> use a single leading `%` on the command line or a double leading `%%` when used in a batch file.

Source: [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: sory for my fault it works now :)